# multiple set of check box?

Tags: javascript

im having a set of multiple check bxes, like one set contain 3 check box share same name another set contain 3 check sharing same name . how can i get the value of these two different set of check box using a single code .

```
    var form = $('usersurvey');
    checkboxes = form.getInputs('checkbox');
    for(count=0; count< checkboxes.length; count++){
        if(checkboxes[count].checked){
            retValue=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return retValue;          
}
```

im tried with this code but it fetch all the check boxes , i want only that have the same name, i used prototype.js

Comment: var form = $('usersurvey');
  checkboxes = form.getInputs('checkbox');
 for(count=0;count<checkboxes.length;count++)
 {
  if(checkboxes[count].checked)
  {
     retValue=true;
     break;
  }
 }
 return retValue;    
   }

Comment: var form = $('usersurvey');
  checkboxes = form.getInputs('checkbox');
 for(count=0;count<checkboxes.length;count++)
 {
  if(checkboxes[count].checked)
  {
    checkboxes[count].value;
  }
 }
     
   } this one is better one

Comment: @Thrustmaster : check the last one, it doesnt work for me , bcoz m having two set of check box, in my code it fetch all the check box value from both the set

Comment: How about iterating over `document.forms[formName].elements[checkboxName]` in a loop (as a checkbox), may be?

Comment: this doesnt work for my application at a time i will tak eonly one set of check box, i need to iterate using name or class name, any solution

Answer (score 1):

if you give each set of checkboxes a different class you could select them using jquery like:

```
$(".className").each(function(index, element) { ... });
```

for instance. somebody may be able to improve on this solution by selecting by name (i wasnt sure if you could do that, i always just select by class).

EDIT: sorry i should elaborate probably. the $(".className") piece will select all the checkboxes of class 'className'. since it sounds like you want to DO something with each of them though, i just added the each call on the end. inside the each call, you can define a function (shown) that will do something for each checkbox that was selected. reference the jquery each docs here:

http://api.jquery.com/each/